# how to define a range of cells as an object

Tags: excel, vba, charts, range

I have a code where i first select a group of cells and then i create a chart. these cells are inputs, so the chart is update whenever new entries come.
part of the code follows. I would need to define the source range as the selection of cells i had previously. Any idea of how I could do that?

```
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 5)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(1, 0)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Blad3!$B$3:$G$75")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
```

Comment: `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Selection`

Comment: the selection is, now, the chart, then it doesnt select my range

Comment: You don't have to select the chart to modify it, that way the cells you selected remains active. Another way is to create a Range variable which would save the selection and then set the chart source with that variable

Comment: the first proposal of yours didnt work, i receive run-time error'13', type mismatch.
i tried to save the range, but it didnt work either.
tried defining a variable as a range, then using 'set variable = range(selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Sheets("blad3")
    lastRow = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Blad1").Select
    Range("C11").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Blad3").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("e3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A3").Select

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Blad3").Range("b3:E" & lastRow)
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution: instead of using ActiveChart, use a variable for the newly created Chart:

```
Dim c As Chart

Range("whatever").Select
Set c = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
c.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
c.SetSourceData Source:=Selection
c.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
```

Or alternatively, without using any variable, with the help of `With` :

```
Range("whatever").Select
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=Selection
    .SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
    '...
End With
```

Second solution: you can save the selection inside a variable:

```
Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("whatever")
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=r
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
```

You can use both methods of course.

Comment: i got the thought involved in all of them, but none of them worked, for my surprise =/
for the first one i received error msg, for the others the graph wouldnt update with the source data

Comment: @user3796821 I forgot the `.Chart` after `AddChart`. I've updated my answer. 3rd one should have worked however

Comment: still nothing. it doesnt recogzize the source range =/

Comment: on the first one- source:= selection doesnt return the graph
on the second one - same problem: doesnt return the graph
on the third one - when i change Set r = Range("whatever") to Set r = Range(Selection, Selection), the codes run (no error msgs), but there is no response in the graph, as if the line regarding the source wasnt there

Comment: @user3796821 `Set r = Selection` for the 3rd. For 1 & 2 you mean that the graph is not created but it doesn't yield any error?

Comment: for 1 and 2 it wouldnt plot the graph. only lines were displayed

Comment: @user3796821 But you chose lines : `ChartType = xlLine`

Comment: thats what macro recorder gave me. it doesnt work properly without that line, apparently. I found another way to do it. ill post it